# Google Speech to Text API filler words

Tags: google-speech-to-text-api

I have worked out how to use google speech to text API but I need the text transcription include filler works like "um ar like" ect. I believe these are auto flited out. Does anybody know how I can have these words included in the text transcription?

Answer (score 0):

May be with some expression tokens like {thinking} {long pause}, similar to how authors of book writers explain the character's speech.

Comment: Hi thanks but what do you mean by expression tokens I know the google Speech to text API has class tokens but I don't see either  {thinking} {long pause} in there